# Jquery image gallery for right and left navigation

Tags: jquery, css

I have this image gallery using jquery which I should create from scratch. I can't start with part of left and right navigation wherein it should navigate to each image previewing in full view and giving an active class on right thumbnail icon on right side  for current selected image.

I already made the part that whenever an image is click on right side it will display on full view on left side.

Please help me with right and left navigation on top of putting active class on current image. I actually started on it but it won't push through in all images.

Here's the fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/ftLnpp0z/

```
    $('#rightnav').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newsrc = $('.img').next().attr("src");
        $('#imgfullview').attr('src', newsrc).load(function(){
            this.width;   
        });
    });

    $('#leftnav').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newsrc = $('.img').prev().attr("src");
        $('#imgfullview').attr('src', newsrc).load(function(){
            this.width;   
        });
    });

    $('.img').click(function () {
        $(".img.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var newsrc = $(this).attr("src");

        $('#imgfullview').attr('src', newsrc).load(function(){
          this.width;   
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem on by creating my own programming logic for previous and next button at http://mcristuta.site40.net/Image_Gallery/